# Django Loading data independantly in a partial

Tags: django, models, partials

I have some partial templates which I load in on various pages and sometimes the inclusion of these partials is dynamic, these have their own related models.

At present I am passing models via views to the main page, but is there not a way to load data for these partials independant of the parent page and view?

Just seems like I am duplicating code in the views which cant be right!

Can I not create a custom tag or something which would allow me to load data into the partial irrespective of the data passed in the parent page and its view?

A good example of this is a partial for "latest posts" which exists in a sidebar partial and loads on many different parent templates

Cheers
Kevin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A custom template tag can do this for you. You could write an [inclusion tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags), which will output the rendered template directly:

```
# yourapp/templatetags/appname_tags.py

def latest_posts(num_posts):
    posts = Post.objects.all()[:num_posts]
    return {'posts': posts}
register.inclusion_tag('yourapp/partials/latest_posts.html')(latest_posts)
```

Comment: I have completed whats been listed, added a related directory structure and __init__.py files and also checked Installed_Apps and amended. However it seems I can load the template tag library without error {% load component_tags %} but when I go to use a tag {% nav_categories %} I just keep getting an error for "Invalid Block Tag: nav_categories"

Comment: are you sure you registered the tag?

Comment: Ignore me, I had the register stuff in the wrong place with respect to sequence. ;-)